# Can I update the hostname of a Docker Node?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Currently all my nodes have the name **ubuntu-yakkety**.

```
docker node ls

ID                           HOSTNAME        STATUS  AVAILABILITY  MANAGER STATUS
d7rdq4n4dmrkhyz4ov7ldr31e    ubuntu-yakkety  Ready   Active        
iddxyuic586lnla6aw700rdwc    ubuntu-yakkety  Ready   Active        
zxcr1yvveccj4soyh2hsjjebk *  ubuntu-yakkety  Ready   Active        Leader
```

In order to create better filters that would be great if I could update **node's hostname** as **`node-01`** **`node-02`** ... **`node-99`**

However, I couldn't find any way to accomplish it in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/node/).

**1) Is it possible to update the hostname of an existing Docker node?**

**2) Is it possible giving a name to a node while joining to swarm?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. change hostname: `hostname ***` or `vi /etc/hosts`
2. restart docker: `sudo systemctl restart docker`

You can see 'Name' user `docker info`

Comment: Sorry but, I have changed my /etc/hosts and restarted but it doesn't changed anything so far... any other thing to do?

Comment: after doing so, it seems docker node cannot detect the new hostName,  
`Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 2 desc = The swarm does not have a leader. It's possible that too few managers are online. Make sure more than half of the managers are online.`

Comment: I left the swarm, edited the hosts file, restarted docker and re-joined the swarm. No change.

Answer (score 6):

This trio works well:

```
echo '127.0.0.1 <hostname>' | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname <hostname>
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to login each nodes and set the node hostname use command:

```
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname <hostname>
```

Once you changed all nodes hostname, go the the manager node and restart your docker, after that you should be good.